# Floated image left, text align center. After image, links don't line up

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

UPDATED: At the top of my page, I have an image floated left.  Next to it, I have a list of links that are text-align: center;  After the image, the last link is centered, although it is centered on the div and does not center from the image which is floated left.

Here is a link to the UPDATED fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/ewcsfce9/6/

The CSS:

```
h2 {text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    }

h2 a {
    text-align: center;
}

a.link {
    color: #00008A;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.link:hover{
    color: orange; 
    font-size: 150%;
}

div.logo {
   float: left;
   width: 30%;
} 

div.links {
   float: right;
   width: 70%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <div class="logo">
    <a href=https://answers.aseba.org/>
         <img src="http://www.aseba.org/graphics/ASEBA%20Logosmall.jpg" alt="ASEBA Logo">
   </a>
</div>

 <div class="links">
     <h2>
         <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-web">ASEBA-WEB Knowledgebase</a>
         </strong>   
    </h2>
<br>
     <h2>
         <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-pc">ASEBA-PC Knowledgebase</a>
         </strong>
     </h2>
<br>
     <h2>
          <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-network">ASEBA-Network Knowledgebase</a>
      </strong>
     </h2>
  <br>
     <h2>
         <strong>
               <a class="link" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIzvez_ZzkpM83-kInJX1HQ" target="_blank">ASEBA Support YouTube Channel!</a>
    </strong>
 </h2>
<br>
     <h2>
       <strong>
           <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/">Complete ASEBA Knowledgebase</a>
   </strong>
<br>       
 </h2>
 </div>
<hr>
```

I realize I have a few options.  One would be creating a "blank" element, that floats left, underneath the image, that is the same width as the image itself.  The other, is to remake the logo bigger.

How can I get the links to stay floated in the center, relative to the logo?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the logo to be on left and the links to be centered at the bottom of the logo?

Comment: I want the image on the left, and the links centered relative to the logo... In the fiddle, you notice the first two links are centered relative to the logo, and below, the links are centered relative to the div.

Comment: Check this and tell me is this what you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/firnas10/6cLgdmst/

Comment: It's because of the height of the div. Set the height of div.logo to be something like 5000px and you'll see what I mean.  You need to sort that

Comment: @john_h Pls check my fiddle its updated

Comment: Thank you... I changed the height of the div.logo to 200px, now it is spaced nice and evenly.  I knew i overlooked something simple, thank you very much for your help!  PS. here is a link to the updated fiddle, thanks Mohamed and Diginari! https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/ewcsfce9/

Comment: I added an answer which works with any height

Comment: You can just add `margin-bottom: 100%;` to div.logo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
h2 {text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    }

h2 a {
    text-align: center;
}

a.link {
    color: #00008A;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.link:hover{
    color: orange; 
    font-size: 150%;
}

div.logo {
 width:30%;
 float:left;
} 
div.links {
  width:70%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">

 <div class="logo">
    <a href="https://answers.aseba.org/">
         <img src="http://www.aseba.org/graphics/ASEBA%20Logosmall.jpg" alt="ASEBA Logo">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="links">



     <h2>
         <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-web">ASEBA-WEB Knowledgebase</a>
         </strong>   
    </h2>
<br>
     <h2>
         <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-pc">ASEBA-PC Knowledgebase</a>
         </strong>
     </h2>
<br>
     <h2>
          <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-network">ASEBA-Network Knowledgebase</a>
      </strong>
     </h2>
  <br>
     <h2>
         <strong>
               <a class="link" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIzvez_ZzkpM83-kInJX1HQ" target="_blank">ASEBA Support YouTube Channel!</a>
    </strong>
 </h2>
<br>
     <h2>
       <strong>
           <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/">Complete ASEBA Knowledgebase</a>
   </strong>
<br>       
 </h2>

<hr>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is perfect because now I don't need to worry about the height if I add anymore links.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thanks, accept answer if it's helped you buddy @john_h

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a div around the links then a containing div around both.

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/p7d35mjs/

```
    <div class="container">

<div class="logo">
    <a href=https://answers.aseba.org/>
        <img src="http://www.aseba.org/graphics/ASEBA%20Logosmall.jpg" alt="ASEBA Logo">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="links">


 <h2>
     <strong>
          <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-web">ASEBA-WEB Knowledgebase</a>
         </strong>   
    </h2>
    <br/>
     <h2>
         <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-pc">ASEBA-PC Knowledgebase</a>
         </strong>
     </h2>
     <br/>
     <h2>
          <strong>
              <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/category/aseba-network">ASEBA-Network Knowledgebase</a>
      </strong>
     </h2>
     <br/>
     <h2>
         <strong>
               <a class="link" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIzvez_ZzkpM83-kInJX1HQ" target="_blank">ASEBA Support YouTube Channel!</a>
         </strong>
     </h2>
     <br/>
     <h2>
       <strong>
           <a class="link" href="https://answers.aseba.org/">Complete ASEBA Knowledgebase</a>
       </strong>    
     </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    }

h2 a {
    text-align: center;
}

a.link {
    color: #00008A;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.link:hover{
    color: orange; 
    /*font-size: 150%;*/
}

div.logo {
   float: left;
} 

div.links {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change:

```
div.logo {
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewcsfce9/4/

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant but, try:

```
div.logo {
 float: left;
 height: 800px;
}
```